# jQuery autocomplete: How to call a getJson after something is chosen in the result?

Tags: jquery

I have a form and the "Name" input text is using jQuery autocomplete. What I needed was when I select a name in the list result of autocomplete, I fill the other input texts (date of birth, telephone etc) based upon the name selected.

Does anyone know how to make this second ajax call after a name is chosen?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the select ID from where the names are is "thenames", you can do something like:

```
$("#thenames").change(function (){
  var params = {
    "id": $(this).val()
  };

  $.getJSON("person_details.php", params, function (jsonData){
    // Fill the rest of input texts.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give the input that has the autocomplete plugin applied to it an ID. For example, "myNames". The others could be "myDOB" and "myTelephoneNum".

```
$("#myNames").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "getRestOfData.cfm",
    data: {newSelection:$(this).val()},
    success: function(data) {
      data = $.trim(data);
      //from here just fill in the rest of the fields with the received data
      //$("myDOB").val("");
      //$("myTelephoneNum").val("")
    }
  });
});
```